# Error 'Couldn't start client Python Tools' when trying to work with Jupyter notebook in VS Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

As of this morning, I'm getting 2 errors in VS Code when opening a Jupyter notebook. I'm able to run code cells and all, but can't figure out what's going on here. I'm using Windows 10, VS Code with the Python extension.

I have tried to uninstall and reinstall VS Code, Python, all VS Code extensions. I'm still new to all of this, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Errors:
Couldn't start client Python Tools
Invalid uri, not a notebook: \profiles$\reederm\Documents\Scripts\Python\CombineCSV\Untitled-1.ipynb
```

Also seeing this in the Python Language Server output pane:

```
[Info  - 3:39:06 PM] Pylance language server 2021.9.0 (pyright 21562654) starting
[Info  - 3:39:06 PM] Server root directory: c:\Users\reederm\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2021.9.0\dist
[Error - 3:39:06 PM] Server initialization failed.
Error: Invalid uri, not a notebook: \profiles$\reederm\Documents\Scripts\Python\CombineCSV\Untitled-1.ipynb
    at getTextDocumentWrapper (c:\Users\reederm\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.9.1191016588\out\client\extension.js:59:455419)
    at g.hasFiredOpen (c:\Users\reederm\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.9.1191016588\out\client\extension.js:59:447486)
    at m.didOpen (c:\Users\reederm\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.9.1191016588\out\client\extension.js:59:456508)
    at h.callNext (c:\Users\reederm\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.9.1191016588\out\client\extension.js:59:464938)
    at h.didOpen (c:\Users\reederm\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.9.1191016588\out\client\extension.js:59:462345)
    at c:\Users\reederm\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.9.1191016588\out\client\extension.js:9:104087
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at T.register (c:\Users\reederm\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.9.1191016588\out\client\extension.js:9:103867)
    at T.initialize (c:\Users\reederm\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.9.1191016588\out\client\extension.js:9:103586)
    at _.initializeFeatures (c:\Users\reederm\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.9.1191016588\out\client\extension.js:9:153665)
    at c:\Users\reederm\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.9.1191016588\out\client\extension.js:9:145193
```

Comment: What is `\profiles$` path? A network device?

Comment: Yea, the actual windows path is \\servername\profiles$\... It is where the "My Documents" folder is mapped to.

Comment: Seems to work fine if I use a local path, like C:\test. So I guess it has something to do with the network path, but I could swear it was working fine yesterday.

Comment: You should try using Windows Explorer to actually mount the file to a named drive? Otherwise, Spark doesn't really handle Sambda/NFS storage that well